# Создание объекта в другом классе Python

Tags: python, ооп, объекты

Программа реализует генетический алгоритм для поиска максимума функции.

Проблема, как я понимаю, заключается в том, что при объявлении класса Python не видит другие классы.

**Ошибка:** `NameError: name [NameClass] is not defined.`

Буду благодарен за подсказки и советы, в какую сторону копать.

Код представлен по [ссылке](https://repl.it/Dojk/0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас при определении класса Сhromosome первая буква - русская С.